# Inventory Class

Tags: c#, class

I have created an Inventory Class but I don't know how to retrieve information from it. I know how to go over it in a foreach loop and display all items, but I don't know how to see if YoYo is in there and if it is, print the Name, Cost and Quantity to a label. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Some code would be good.  Until we know what your Inventory class looks like, there's not much we can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're going beyond an Inventory class and creating a Product class as well.  Object-oriented languages are all about encapsulation and information hiding.   Embed the output of the Product in a method for that object.  Clients can simply call it that way instead of having to repeat it all over the place.

I'd also recommend a find method in your Inventory class that lets you search for a Product instance.  You might want to search by name now, but what about cost, category, or manufacturer?  Perhaps you'll want to extend it later.

I agree with Marc's dictionary recommendation, but I would advise that you made that part of Inventory's private implementation.  You're adding an extra bit of abstraction that makes an Inventory something more than a mere dictionary.

I think strings and data structures are wonderful, but too often these primitives leak into code when hiding them in an object would be much better for clients.  That's what I think good object-oriented design is all about.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention `foreach`, it sounds like it implements `IEnumerable<T>`. In which case, if you are using C# 3.0 / LINQ, something like:

```
var yoyo = inventory.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == "YoYo");
if(yoyo != null) { // found it
    Console.WriteLine(yoyo.Cost); // etc
}
```

You might also look at dictionaries if you have a lot of data...